# Invalid conversion while trying to save array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

PHP:     8.1
CakePHP: 4.4.
Postgres: 13

**Problem**: **While generating entity `Block`, after setting data, the `val` property is always set to null**

Table definition

```
create table blocks
(
    id         integer generated always as identity
    val        integer[]
);
```

Im trying to call **createNewBlock** method (Entity class is completely empty, just extends Cake\ORM\Entity):

```
class BlocksTable extends Table {
    public function initialize(array $config): void {
        $this->setTable('blocks');
        $this->setEntityClass('App\Model\Entity\Block');
    }

    public function createNewBlock(int ...$val): Block {
        return $this->newEntity([
            'val' => $val
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the result

```
App\Model\Entity\Block Object
(
    [val] => 
)
```

I expected val to be an array but it's always set to null

So i was digging a little bit and dont know why method **_buildPropertyMap** from **Cake\ORM\Marshaller** returns **columnType = string** for column **val**

Is there any quick fix for that ?

Comment: I don't see arrays listed at [Data Types](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#data-types). CakePHP needs to work with different database engines. The PostgreSQL driver is seemingly applying a sane common type and defaulting to text, just like it does with JSON. In that same document you have explanations to build custom types (though someone might have written a plugin).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález
Yea, MB, i should check that. Ty